# Problema com iframe

Tags: javascript

Tento abrir um link simples em um iframe, e ele lança esse erro:

> Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Esse é o código completo:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Testing Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe width="400" height="215" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com.br"> </iframe><br />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pode te ajudar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem nada errado com o seu código, o problema é a segurança do servidor que você está chamando.

O site "google.com.br" definiu que ele não pode ser aberto em iframes de outros dominios que não seja "google.com.br".

Para usar um iframe você tem que importar uma página sua mesmo, ou de algum site menos seguro, como bitbucket por exemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Testing Page</title>
</head>

    <body>
            <iframe width="400" height="215" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://bitbucket.com"> </iframe><br />
    </body>

</html>
```